# jqGrid pginput Size

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there a jqGrid way to change the size of `pginput`?  This is what it defaults to for me:

```
<input class="ui-pg-input" type="text" role="textbox" value="0" maxlength="7" size="2">
```

I haven't found one so I did the following:

```
$('.ui-pg-input').attr('size', 6);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid don't have any option to set `size` attribute of the input box of the pager. It use just the following code (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2124))

```
pginp= "<td dir='"+dir+"'>" +
    $.jgrid.format(ts.p.pgtext || "",
        "<input class='ui-pg-input' type='text' size='2' maxlength='7' value='0' role='textbox'/>",
        "<span id='sp_1_"+$.jgrid.jqID(pgid)+"'></span>")+"</td>";
```

where `pgtext` will be defined in the language specific file. The file `grid.locale-en.js` for example contains `text : "Page {0} of {1}"`. The method `$.jgrid.format` is simple (see [the code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L28-L34)). It makes just text substitutions of numbers enclosed in `{}` (like `{0}`, `{1}` and `{2}`).

In general you can do set the value of `size` attribute by using the `pgtext`:

```
pgtext: "Page <input class='ui-pg-input' type='text' size='6' maxlength='7' value='0' role='textbox'/> of {1}",
```

To tell the truth I would not find such way nice, but it would work. In my opinion the code

```
$('.ui-pg-input').attr('size', 6);
```

which you use currently is good enough.